"Lock Pools" or other solutions for handling memory intensive operations in a .NET Framework backend?
My backend application takes byte arrays that represent image data and applies certain transformations to it, like changing the resolution and such, and then stores this modified data to disk.
During some analysis I found that if there are many concurrent requests to use this transformation utility, the memory usage of the server application will spike and on weak hardware may result in an OutOfMemoryException.
To solve the issue temporarily I wrapped the memory intensive operation in a lock-block, kind of like so:
        public byte[] TransformImage(byte[] imageBytes)
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                // Do memory intensive work
            }
        }

This works, but also has the result, that machines that could theoretically handle multiple concurrent requests like this now are stuck only being able to process one at a time, potentially impacting the UX.
I was thinking that I could assign a "Lock-Pool" or such, which I can extend according to available memory, but the lack of sources describing such a solution hint that I may use a wrong approach here.
Any suggestions?

Seems to be a job for a SemaphoreSlim. If your software provides some configuration the admin could say how many parallel transformations can be run and you use that number in the ctor of the semaphore.

@Oliver Thank you very much. That seems to be exactly what I need. I had to use a ThreadLocal variable to avoid threads reserving the Semaphore multiple times, because I have multiple entry points, but otherwise this solution seems to work. I'll gladly mark this as answer if you post it as such.

while Oliver's suggestion is the go, how much RAM does the server have and how much are you using?

@MitchWheat Unfortunately I can't disclose details, but there's a variety of hardware the software runs on. From small virtual servers with barely any memory available to more performant dedicated servers that of course don't run into these issues.

You could also try to read how much memory is available on the host computer and allocate your semaphore this way.

@TheodorZoulias Thanks for the heads-up. I fixed it :)
Allocating semaphores according to available memory is something I'll consider if it comes up again. Maybe limiting the available semaphores to one on machines with considerably low available memory. But at that point we should probably reconsider letting that server handle image manipulation, since it really seems quite resource intensive.

If you have to limit concurrent usage of a method to more than one, the correct class to use would potentially be a SemaphoreSlim:

Represents a lightweight alternative to Semaphore that limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.

Just right from the mentioned documenation here is an example on how you can restrict the maximum concurrent tasks that will perform an action:
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    // A padding interval to make the output more orderly.
    private static int padding;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create the semaphore.
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tasks can enter the semaphore.",
                          semaphore.CurrentCount);
        Task[] tasks = new Task[5];

        // Create and start five numbered tasks.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Each task begins by requesting the semaphore.
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} begins and waits for the semaphore.",
                                  Task.CurrentId);
                
                int semaphoreCount;
                semaphore.Wait();
                try
                {
                    Interlocked.Add(ref padding, 100);

                    Console.WriteLine("Task {0} enters the semaphore.", Task.CurrentId);

                    // The task just sleeps for 1+ seconds.
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 + padding);
                }
                finally {
                    semaphoreCount = semaphore.Release();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} releases the semaphore; previous count: {1}.",
                                  Task.CurrentId, semaphoreCount);
            });
        }

        // Wait for half a second, to allow all the tasks to start and block.
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        // Restore the semaphore count to its maximum value.
        Console.Write("Main thread calls Release(3) --> ");
        semaphore.Release(3);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tasks can enter the semaphore.",
                          semaphore.CurrentCount);
        // Main thread waits for the tasks to complete.
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       0 tasks can enter the semaphore.
//       Task 1 begins and waits for the semaphore.
//       Task 5 begins and waits for the semaphore.
//       Task 2 begins and waits for the semaphore.
//       Task 4 begins and waits for the semaphore.
//       Task 3 begins and waits for the semaphore.
//       Main thread calls Release(3) --> 3 tasks can enter the semaphore.
//       Task 4 enters the semaphore.
//       Task 1 enters the semaphore.
//       Task 3 enters the semaphore.
//       Task 4 releases the semaphore; previous count: 0.
//       Task 2 enters the semaphore.
//       Task 1 releases the semaphore; previous count: 0.
//       Task 3 releases the semaphore; previous count: 0.
//       Task 5 enters the semaphore.
//       Task 2 releases the semaphore; previous count: 1.
//       Task 5 releases the semaphore; previous count: 2.
//       Main thread exits.


Based on Oliver's answer I settled on the below solution for now:
private readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3, 3);
private readonly ThreadLocal<bool> SemaphoreHeld = new ThreadLocal<bool>(() => false);

public byte[] TransformImage(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    AcquireSemaphore();
    try
    {
        // Do memory intensive work
    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseSemaphore();
    }
}

private void AcquireSemaphore()
{
    if (!SemaphoreHeld.Value)
    {
        Semaphore.Wait();
        SemaphoreHeld.Value = true;
    }
}

private void ReleaseSemaphore()
{
    if (SemaphoreHeld.Value)
    {
        Semaphore.Release();
        SemaphoreHeld.Value = false;
    }
}

In some methods I call other functions that would acquire the same semaphore. Using the ThreadLocal allows me to check if the current thread already acquired one and would then skip acquiring it again.
One extension I might include in the future is setting the amount of available semaphores according to the available memory.

What's the intention behind the ThreadLocal<bool> field? Are you trying to make the SemaphoreSlim reentrant? If so, I think that your implementation is buggy. A reentrant lock should be actually released when a number of Release() equal to the number of Acquire() have been issued. It seems that you are releasing it prematurely.

@TheodorZoulias Nice catch. I'm kind of retrofitting this in some code that was written without concurrency in mind. I agree with you, but in my case it works fine. TransformImage is overloaded and some of the overloads call eachother. All their bodies are wrapped in the same try/finally as in the example. Not quite happy with it no matter how I approach it admittedly.

Well, implementing a reentrant Semaphore is not part of the question, so your answer is probably off topic here.
So I'll have to downvote it, sorry. Even if it was on topic, this implementation violates most developers' expectations of how a
reentrant Semaphore is supposed to work, so I would still have to downvote it (unless this atypical behavior was explicitly requested in the question).
If you are really interested in a reentrant Semaphore, a relevant question is here, you don't have to ask a new one.

@TheodorZoulias Fair point, lol.
